# Miscrosoft Graph API 'UnableToDeserializePostBody' error after sending a post request to update a contact

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

I'm trying to update a new contact with a schema extension by calling the Microsoft Graph API using the MS Graph sdk in Java.
So far, every call for this specific action returns an `UnableToDeserializePostBody` error.

My code to checks for a shema extension:

```
SchemaExtensionCollectionPage response = graphClient.schemaExtensions().buildRequest().get();
List<SchemaExtension> extensions = fetchAll(response);
contactExtension = extensions.stream()
    .filter(e-> (contactExtensionId).equals(e.id)) //contactExtensionId fetched from internal DB
    .findAny().orElse(null);

if(contactExtension == null)
{
    contactExtension = new SchemaExtension();
    contactExtension.id = contactExtensionId;
    contactExtension.description = "Contact extension";
    LinkedList<String> targetTypesList = new LinkedList<>();
    targetTypesList.add("contact");
    contactExtension.targetTypes = targetTypesList;
    
    LinkedList<ExtensionSchemaProperty> propertiesList = new LinkedList<>();
    ExtensionSchemaProperty tenantProperty = new ExtensionSchemaProperty();
    tenantProperty.name = EXTENSION_PROPERTY_TENANT;
    tenantProperty.type = "String";
    propertiesList.add(tenantProperty);
    ExtensionSchemaProperty idProperty = new ExtensionSchemaProperty();
    idProperty.name = EXTENSION_PROPERTY_ID;
    idProperty.type = "String";
    propertiesList.add(idProperty);
    contactExtension.properties = propertiesList;
    
    contactExtension = graphClient.schemaExtensions()
            .buildRequest()
            .post(contactExtension);
            
    logger.info("Contact Extension created : " + contactExtension.id);
}
```

Here's the extension for the contact:

```
public static class ContactExtension extends Extension
{
    @SerializedName(value = "tenant", alternate = {"Tenant"})
    @Expose
    @Nullable
    public String tenant;
    
    @SerializedName(value = "entityId", alternate = {"EntityId"})
    @Expose
    @Nullable
    public String entityId;
}
```

And here is how I try to update the contact following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups?tabs=java) as much as I can :

```
Extension ext = graphClient.users(targetUser.id)
    .contacts(contact.id)
    .extensions(this.contactExtension.id)
    .buildRequest()
    .post(contactExt);
```

The stack trace i get:

```
Jul 12, 2023 1:53:03 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
    SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 408Graph service exception
    Jul 12, 2023 1:53:03 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
    SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: UnableToDeserializePostBody
    Error message: were unable to deserialize

    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/contacts/{contacts}/extensions/extdtlnlmgg_contactMetaData
    SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.49.0
        [...]

        400 : Bad Request
[...]

        [Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
    Jul 12, 2023 1:53:03 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
    SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 408Graph service exception
    Jul 12, 2023 1:53:03 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
    SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: UnableToDeserializePostBody
    Error message: were unable to deserialize

    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/contacts/{contacts}/extensions/extdtlnlmgg_contactMetaData
    SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.49.0
        [...]

        400 : Bad Request
[...]

        [Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
        13:53:03,442  ERROR [cerebro.manager.MsGraphHelper] Mails TES error
    com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: UnableToDeserializePostBody
    Error message: were unable to deserialize

    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/contacts/{contacts}/extensions/extdtlnlmgg_contactMetaData
    SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.49.0
        [...]

        400 : Bad Request
[...]

        [Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromResponse(GraphServiceException.java:419)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromResponse(GraphServiceException.java:378)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleErrorResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:512)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.processResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:442)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:408)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:225)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:202)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:335)
```

Is there anyone who might have a clue about what steps I should take or the source of the issue?
The official documentation regarding Java in this matter is quite limited.